# How to write a query to get unique elements from a relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 entities with a many to many relation. Users - Roles_Users - Roles

How can write a query that returns to me all the users that only has exactly one role which is the role name "customer". I wrote something like this:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles_users`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
INNER JOIN `roles` ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id`
WHERE roles.name not in ('admin' , 'sac', 'superadmin',  'customer_service' ,  'supplier');
```

but it still brought to me users that has more than the role 'customer'.

I need the users that has ONLY the role of 'customer' and nothing else

Comment: table structures with example data would help, can you provide a sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Why I got 2 down votes???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would solve it:

```
SELECT `users`.* 
FROM `users`
WHERE id IN
 (
   SELECT `roles_users`.`user_id`
   FROM `roles_users`
   INNER JOIN `roles`
   ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id`
   GROUP BY `roles_users`.`user_id`
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1                 -- only a single role
      AND MAX(roles.name) = 'customer' -- and this role is 'customer'
 )
```

Btw, there's no need to use all those backticks:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE id IN
 (
   SELECT roles_users.user_id
   FROM roles_users
   JOIN roles
     ON roles.id = roles_users.role_id
   GROUP BY roles_users.user_id
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1                 -- only a single role
      AND MAX(roles.name) = 'customer' -- and this role is 'customer'
 )
```

Isn't this easier to read (and write)?

Comment: Thanks! It worked! The backticks are there because of the Ruby's to_sql function which for some reason prints like that

Answer (score 0):

Compare role name directly,because using in can get you other non required values

```
   SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles_users`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` INNER JOIN `roles` ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id` WHERE roles.name ='customer'
```

Comment: This one will return users that has at least the role of 'customer'... I need the users that has ONLY the role of 'customer' and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Why not just look users with the specific role?

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` 
JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles_users`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
JOIN `roles` ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id` 
WHERE `roles`.name  = 'customer';
```

Comment: I can't... it returns users which might have other roles as well... I need users where they ONLY have the role of 'customer'

Answer (score 0):

Use a `NOT EXISTS` subquery in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
INNER JOIN roles_users ru ON ru.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id = ru.role_id
WHERE r.name = 'customer'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM roles_users ru1
    WHERE ru1.user_id  = ru.user_id
      AND ru1.role_id <> ru.role_id
  )
```

The `NOT EXISTS` condition will ensure that no other roles are assigned to the user.

A shorter but slower solution could be:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
INNER JOIN roles_users ru ON ru.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id = ru.role_id
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(r.name) = 'customer'
```